# How to count IDs that have a given combination of flags?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like that. I need to choose and count all distinct users, who have title "banner_click" and "order". So I don't understand how to do it in pandas, in SQL you do like UniqExactIf and go on, there I need to find all users, who had both these title.

```
     user         title
0  user_0  banner_click  # has both "banner_click" and "order"
1  user_0         order  #
2  user_1   banner_show
3  user_1         order
4  user_2         order  # also has both "banner_click" and "order"
5  user_2  banner_click  #
```

I have tried "in" but I guess it doesn't work correct

```
main = df.query("title in ('banner_click','order')").agg({'user':'nunique'})
```

Expected output: `2` (user_0 and user2 are a match)

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user_0', 'user_0', 'user_1', 'user_1', 'user_2', 'user_2'],
                   'title': ['banner_click', 'order', 'banner_show', 'order', 'order', 'banner_click']
                  })
```

Comment: Don't use images of code/data, provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: [And yet...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77137750/3001761)

Comment: @jonrsharpe not sure what is the purpose of your comment. I can abstract the operation without necessarily needing a dataset, that makes it an answerable question. Now, I'd love the question to become a better question with a proper MRE to make it a clear example to everyone. I'll try to add one when I have my hands on a decent keyboard, if OP doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin()` to retrieve the relevant rows and then use `df.nunique()`.

`df.loc[df['title'].isin(['banner_click', 'order'])]['user'].nunique()`

Comment: This will count users that have either title, not both.

Comment: No, it still gives a lot, I mean that the amount of orders made by 237866 people is 248722.

Comment: When I put two these conditions the amount of users who made orders should be less

Comment: @Коля can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) as requested for us to test the solutions?

Comment: cause not all of these 237866 had such title like "banner_click"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count the users that have both 'banner_click' and 'order'.

One option using sets:

```
N = (df.groupby('user')['title']
       .agg(set)
       .ge({'banner_click', 'order'})
       .sum()
     )
```

Using a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
N = (pd.crosstab(df['user'], df['title'])
       [['banner_click', 'order']]
       .gt(0).all(axis=1)
       .sum()
     )
```

Another approach with sets (maybe less efficient, but easier to understand):

```
banner_click = set(df.loc[df['title'].eq('banner_click'), 'user'])
order = set(df.loc[df['title'].eq('order'), 'user'])

N = len(banner_click & order)
```

Comment: @Коля you're welcome. I'd appreciate if you can [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77137676/edit) add a minimal example in the question, that will improve it's quality and make it useful to future readers.