# How to make conditions in pandas correctly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas. I need to check how banners have influenced orders.
That is why I need to compare date of order and date of such events as "banners_show" and "banners_click". Definitely, the date of order should be later than the date of these two events. And the main thing that I should count the amount of such orders.
[This is my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOMUn.png)
In titles can be "banner_show", "banner_click", "order" and of course date for them.
I expect that I will get the amount of users who made an order after seeing or clicking the banner.

```
     user         title         time
0  user_0  banner_click  2017-02-09 20:24:04   
1  user_0         order  2017-03-20 19:24:04  #user0 clicked a banner and then after a period of time he has bought
2  user_1   banner_show  2017-04-14 20:24:04 
3  user_1         order  2017-02-04 20:24:04 #user1 made an order earlier than he saw a banner, we don't need to count him
4  user_2         order  2017-08-12 20:24:04 #user2 made an order, then he clicked a banner and made an order, we should count him
5  user_2         order  2017-03-12 20:24:04
5  user_2  banner_click  2017-08-11 20:24:04      #
```

I have tried this:

```
banner_click = set(df.loc[df['title'].eq('banner_click'), 'user'])
order = set(df.loc[df['title'].eq('order'), 'user'])

unique_user_buy_from_click= len(banner_click & order)
print(unique_user_buy)
```

Also I tried to use "query", but it doesn't work correct
Expected output: unique users-`2`, total_made_orders - `2` (user_0 and user2 are a match)

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user_0', 'user_0', 'user_1', 'user_1', 'user_2', 'user_2','user_2'],
                   'title': ['banner_click', 'order', 'banner_show', 'order', 'order','order','banner_click']
                  })
```

It would be better if there was the count of unique users who made such orders after seeing this events and also the amount of all orders made by these unique users

Comment: Can you please **stop using images of data** and instead provide a [**reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)? If you don't we'll have to vote to close your question for lacking one. I highly recommend that you [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (again if already done) to make sure that you'll fully aware of how the site works and improve the quality of the Q&A.

Comment: See the other, question, I edited it to add a minimal reproducible example, please do the same here.

Comment: I don't think you have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), you must provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, you'll need to do the following:

1. Group by user and then sort by date.
2. Check if a banner show or banner click event precedes an order event for each user.
3. Count the users that fulfill the condition.

Here's an answer to the problem:

```
# Grouping by user and sorting by date
grouped = df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('date'))

# Check for each user if they have a banner_show or banner_click event before an order
def check_order_after_banner(user_df):
    banner_show_indices = user_df[user_df['title'] == 'banner_show'].index.tolist()
    banner_click_indices = user_df[user_df['title'] == 'banner_click'].index.tolist()
    order_indices = user_df[user_df['title'] == 'order'].index.tolist()
    for order_index in order_indices:
        if any(banner_index < order_index for banner_index in banner_show_indices) or \
           any(banner_index < order_index for banner_index in banner_click_indices):
            return True
    return False
users_with_condition = grouped.groupby('user').apply(check_order_after_banner)
count_users = sum(users_with_condition)
print(count_users)
```

To achieve this, you can group your dataframe by user and then sort by date. Afterward, for each user, you can check if there is a banner_show or banner_click event that precedes an order event. Here's a solution:

```
# Grouping by user and sorting by date
grouped = df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('date'))
# Check for each user if they have a banner_show or banner_click event before an order
def check_order_after_banner(user_df):
    banner_show_indices = user_df[user_df['title'] == 'banner_show'].index.tolist()
    banner_click_indices = user_df[user_df['title'] == 'banner_click'].index.tolist()
    order_indices = user_df[user_df['title'] == 'order'].index.tolist()
    
    for order_index in order_indices:
        if any(banner_index < order_index for banner_index in banner_show_indices) or \
           any(banner_index < order_index for banner_index in banner_click_indices):
            return True
    return False

users_with_condition = grouped.groupby('user').apply(check_order_after_banner)
count_users = sum(users_with_condition)

print(count_users)
```

This solution will give you the count of users who placed an order after viewing or clicking on a banner.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @КоляГруздис are you going to provide a MRE or not?

Comment: maybe some other decisions, i really need that

Comment: @mozway There is a problem that I do not know how to do that

Comment: @КоляГруздис I linked you to a [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that explains in detail how to do that, there is also the [help on MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I [edited your previous question with a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77137676/16343464), that should be more than enough for you to know what to do. Have you even checked any of that? Questions with a proper MRE often get good answer within minutes, those with images get mostly bad answers, no answer, or get closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
# ensure data is sorted by date
df = df.sort_values(by=['user', 'time'])

# flag rows after the banner was seen/clicked
banner_seen = (df['title'].str.startswith('banner')
               .groupby(df['user']).cummax()
              )

N = df.loc[df['title'].eq('order') & banner_seen, 'user'].nunique()
```

Output: `2`

Intermediates:

```
     user         title                 time  banner_seen  order  order_after_banner
0  user_0  banner_click  2017-02-09 20:24:04         True  False               False
1  user_0         order  2017-03-20 19:24:04         True   True                True
3  user_1         order  2017-02-04 20:24:04        False   True               False
2  user_1   banner_show  2017-04-14 20:24:04         True  False               False
5  user_2         order  2017-03-12 20:24:04        False   True               False
5  user_2  banner_click  2017-08-11 20:24:04         True  False               False
4  user_2         order  2017-08-12 20:24:04         True   True                True
```

To get the counts of order, per user, after seeing a banner:

```
(df['title'].eq('order') & banner_seen).groupby(df['user']).sum()
```

Output:

```
user
user_0    1
user_1    0
user_2    1
Name: title, dtype: int64
```

Comment: How can I get an output as you have?

Comment: @КоляГруздис I don't understand your question